# User Profile URL with third level domain format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, w3c

Would it be possible to change the user profile address to:  **{username}.domainname.com** instead of **domainname.com/{username}** (presently I have this)?

What is this third level domain format and how can I accomplish the same in my ASP.Net MVC application?  I have been asked to make this change in my site for visiting the user profile.  What is the advantage of having this format and how can I implement the same?

How could this be accomplished if I decided to make this change?

Comment: Do you know of any site that uses this URL scheme?  It's not practical because that is the realm of the DNS, not your application.  You'd have to add a new C Record in the DNS for every user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845056/